# Multiresponse Poisson regression in R

Tags: poisson-regression, graphical-model, multivariate-regression, generalized-least-squares

Can I apply generalised linear regression to a **multiresponse** setting?

I mean the regression **$Y = \beta X + \epsilon$**

where $\beta$ is a parameter matrix and $Y$ is a response vector, in my case multivariate Poisson distributed.

Can I apply glm() in R to estimate parameter matrix?

Comment: Do you mean a simple poisson regression with count data? **summary(parametersYouWantToKnow <- glm(DependentVariable ~ indVar1 + indVar2, family="poisson", data=p))**

Comment: You cannot apply glm to such multiresponse data, but there is a CRAN package you can use, VGAM. See https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~yee/VGAM/.   That is a huge package!

Comment: Some could think this is close to being off-topic here. Could you augment the question with some information on the problem to which you want to apply multi-response Poisson regression, to give it more of a statistical content?

Comment: @kjetil b halvorsen: I have a network of correlated Poisson variables Y that, in log-domain, depend linearly on regressors X AND possibly some other networkvariables Y. Therefore an estimation of parameter matrix b implies a multiresponse GLM regression.

Comment: Could you add that new information to the original question? Maybe with more details, like number of variables and sample sizes.  Questions which only asks about how to do something in R is considered offtopic here, so please add more statistical content. Did you have a look at VGAM?

Comment: This sounds like a graphical model! see for instance https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5624559/